# Estimating an unknown basis function from a sum of time-scaled versions

Tags: algorithm, numeric

Not sure if this is a 'mathematical' problem or a 'numerical/computational' problem, but I thought would post it here in hope that someone might be able to help point me in the right direction.

Consider a function g(t) in the time-domain that consists of a sum of time-scaled versions of an unknown basis function f(t) ie.

g(t) = f(a_0.t) + f(a_1.t) + ... + f(a_N.t)

where N and the time scaling coefficients (a_0, a_1,..., a_N) are known. We can assume all coefficients are positive and no greater than one. ie. 0 < a_i <= 1.

Observations of g(t) are made at 'M' uniformly sampled discrete points ie. t = [0,1,...,M-1]. It is assumed that g(t) and f(t) are continuous and otherwise "well behaved".

The objective is to obtain an estimate of the function f(t) at the sample points.

One approach I have tried is to express both f(t) and g(t) as polynomials of degree K, equate polynomial coefficients and solve; ie.

g(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{K} g_k.t^k

f(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{K} f_k.t^k

and hence

f_K = g_K / (a_0^K + a_1^K + .... + a_N^K)

f_{K-1} = g_{K-1} / (a_0^(K-1) + a_1^(K-1) + .... + a_N^(K-1))

....etc....

f_0 = g_0 / N

Directly implementing this approach (naively?) suffers from the sensitivity of estimating g(t) with a degree K polynomial. Does anyone know of other approaches to this problem that may be more numerically stable?

Comment: Have you tried a Fourier transform? Fourier frequencies constitute a complete orthogonal basis.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @pjs17. Yes, I have looked at Fourier transforms. It is fairly easily shown that the problem is basically the same in both domains -ie.

f(a_0 t) + ... + f(a_N t)  <=>  F(w/a_0)/a_0 + ... + F(w/a_N)/a_N

Where I have used f(t) <=> F(w) to represent Fourier transform pairs.